# MySQL select rows having common column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table called `conversation_user` containing the relations between the `users` and `conversations` (basically it's storing the users participating in a conversation).

This is how it looks like:

```
----------------------------
| id | conversation | user |
----------------------------
|  1 |            1 |    1 |
|  2 |            1 |    2 |
|  3 |            2 |    4 |
|  4 |            3 |    2 |
|  5 |            3 |    3 |
|  6 |            4 |    1 |
|  7 |            4 |    2 |
|  8 |            4 |    3 |
----------------------------
```

I would like to write a query that given the user IDs of users participating in a conversation it returns the conversation ID (if any).

> Example:
>
> User IDs: [1, 2] => Conversation ID: 1
>   User IDs: [2, 1, 3] => Conversation ID: 4

This is what I was able to achieve so far:

```
SELECT conversation FROM conversation_user WHERE user IN (1, 2) GROUP BY conversation HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Of course this query will return:

```
---------------
| conversation|
---------------
|            1|
|            4|
---------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an exact match.  So, (1, 2) does *not* match conversation 4.

For this, you cannot use a `where` clause for filtering.  Instead:

```
SELECT conversation
FROM conversation_user
GROUP BY conversation
HAVING count(*) = 2 AND
       sum(user in (1, 2)) = count(*);
```

The `= 2` is the number of participants you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function should do the trick:

```
SELECT   `conversation`, GROUP_CONCAT(`user`) AS users
FROM     conversation_user
GROUP BY `conversation`
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 2
```